# How to add constraints to UIStackView inside of a UITableViewCell swift programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios-autolayout, uistackview

I have a function that creates an array `UIStackViews` with `UIButtons` inside of it:

```
func generateStackViews() -> [UIStackView] {
    var stackViewArray = [UIStackView]()
    let finalButtonArray = generateButtons()
    for buttons in finalButtonArray{
        stackViewArray.append(createStackView(subViews: buttons))
    }
    return stackViewArray
}
```

I then add that array to a `tableViewCell`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "First")!
    cell.contentView.addSubview(generateStackViews()[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

Everything works fine, but when I try to add constraints to pin the `stackViews` to the cells, I get this error:

> failure in -[UITableViewCell _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]

I tried adding the constraints in the function that creates the `stackViews` and in the `cellForRowAt` function, tried to pin it to the `contentView`, cell and `tableView`, but neither worked and I got the same error message.

Where is my logic failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call this method to addContraints Programatically.

```
func addSubviewWithConstraint(to parentView: UIView, and childView: UIView, top:CGFloat, bottom:CGFloat, leading:CGFloat, trailing:CGFloat) {
    parentView.addSubview(childView)
    //Below line tells the view to not use AutoResizing
    childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    // set top constraint
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: top)
    // set Bottom constraint
    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: bottom)
    // set leading constraint
    let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: leading)
    // set Bottom constraint
    let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: trailing)
    //Add all constraints to parentView
    parentView.addConstraint(topConstraint)
    parentView.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)
    parentView.addConstraint(leadingConstraint)
    parentView.addConstraint(trailingConstraint)
}
```

and call the above method like this.

```
self.addSubviewWithConstraint(to: cell.contenetView, and: stackView, top: 0, bottom: 0, leading: 0, trailing: 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much this was helpful. I'm a beginner so if you could explain the logic behind this it would be much appreciated